# PhoneGap 2.0 iOS error: /VERSION: No such file or directory

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

while installing the new phonegap ie phonegap 2.0 
I got this error any one please help me to solve this error iam using xcode 4.3.2 ios 5.1:

Missing dependency target "CordovaLib (from CordovaLib.xcodeproj)"

CpResource /VERSION /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuApp-emlsuylgddtbitggsiybbtqsxxmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MenuApp.app/VERSION

```
cd /Users/arjun/Desktop/MenuApp

setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip /VERSION /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuApp-emlsuylgddtbitggsiybbtqsxxmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MenuApp.app
```

error: /VERSION: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also totally new on this PhoneGap world and I had the same problem with iOS version.

Make sure you use version 2.0.0, since at today, version 2.0.1 is missing the .pkg file. Follow the tutorial in PhoneGap.com.

When you run the `./create /user/myhome/documents/HelloWorld com.mydomain.HelloWorld HelloWorld`, and you open the `HelloWorld.xcodeproj`, select the `HelloWorld` project, then go to `Targets`, click the `HelloWorld` item, then go to `Build Phases` tab. Expand the `Target Dependencies` option. There should be a `CordobaLib` item listed, and if there is one, deleted it, and add it again.

It took me hours to find this out, hope it saves time to others!

Comment: Use Phonegp 2.2 (as you already do), there are plenty of ios6 bugs in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

See: (step 25 might help)

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20iOS

Answer (score 1):

Edit `your_project_folder/www/config.xml`

and change

```
preference name="phonegap-version" value="1.9.0"
```

to

```
preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Cordova-2.0.0 dev kit this is caused by having the incorrect Phonegap JavaScript file being loaded in the index.html file. Make sure the following statement

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
```

is loading the phonegap js file that matches the SDK you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your "Your Project" root folder to the same "CordovaLib" root folder.